# Probability question with a hard to find limit as its answer.

Tags: calculus, probability, analysis, probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables. For $n=1,2,3,...$ we have $$\mathbb{P}(X=n)=p(1-p)^n
\\\mathbb{P}(Y=n)=q(1-q)^n$$
For some $p$ and $q$. Find $\mathbb{P}(X\leq Y)$

What I would like to know is:
1. Is my reasoning (the probabilistic part of the question) right?
2. Someone to help me find this limit I have got at the end.
So since these are probabilities we have$p$ and $q$ need to be in $(0,1)$, this follows from the formula for a sum of geometric series. Now, notice that we are interested in finding sum of all $\mathbb{P}(X=n \wedge Y=m)\\$ such that $n\leq m$. So in fact we can take the limit of the partial sums $$\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\mathbb{P}(X=n \wedge Y=m)$$ $X$ and $Y$ are independent so this translates to $$\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\mathbb{P}(X=n)\mathbb{P}(Y=m)=\lim_{m\to \infty}q(1-q)^{m-1}\sum_{n=1}^{m}(1-p)^{n-1}p $$ using geometric series formula we get
$$\lim_{m\to \infty}q(1-q)^{m-1}(1-(1-p)^{m}) $$

and here I am stuck evaluating this limit. I could write down what I tried, but it took me nowhere closer to the result.

Answer (score 1):

$P\{X\leq Y\}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum _{n=1} ^{m} P\{X=n,Y=m\}$. You have written limit instead of sum over $m$. Now try to compute $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} q(1-q)^{m-1}[1-(1-p)^{m}]$. (You will have to sum two geometric series and take the difference).

Comment: Now I see, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this question without calculating any infinite sums. Hint: work out $\mathbb P(X=n\mid\min(X,Y)=n)$.

Comment: I think I get what you mean, You want me to find $\mathbb{P}(X=n | \min(X,Y)=n)$, to get $\mathbb{P}(\min(X,Y)=n | X=n) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X=n | \min(X,Y)=n)\mathbb{P}(X=n)}{\mathbb{P}(\min(X,Y)=n)}$ but I dont know how to get $\mathbb{P}(\min(X,Y)=n)$

Comment: @Kacper $X$ and $Y$ are geometric variables (giving the number of trials up to and including the first success) with success probabilities $p$ and $q$ respectively. So $\min(X,Y)$ gives the first time you get a success in at least one of them, which is geometric with success probability $1-(1-p)(1-q)$.

Comment: How come it can be independent on $n$ ?

Comment: Essentially, because for any $n$ what you are looking at is the probability that $X$ has a success at time $n$, given that $X$ or $Y$ has a success at time $n$ (the factors corresponding to there being no earlier successes will cancel).